# How can you send up to fifty requests per second to a microcontroller (ESP8266) in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest, esp8266

I'm using a microcontroller(ESP8266) as a webserver to serve a webpage. This microcontroller controls a remote car. The webpage sends up to 50 request to the microcontroller to regulate speed and turning angle.

XHR is too slow for this purpose, so I'm changing the source of a hidden image. This doesn't work on any browser availble on iPhone because Apple forces browser developers to use their webkitengine.

```
interv = setInterval(send, 20);
function send() {
  if (autodrive) {
    imgsend.src = "send.php?autodrive=on&sh=" + sh;
  } else {
    imgsend.src = "send.php?autodrive=off&x=" + x + "&y=" + y + "&sh=" + sh;
  }
}
```

There should be up to 50 Request per second to microcontroller. In reality there is only one after a few seconds. Is there any way to fix this? Please keep in mind, that the microcontroller has only limited power.

Comment: Can your controller do websockets, as that will handle 50 reqs per sec no problem, and is also compatible with most browsers.  And of course very resourse friendly.

Comment: This might help  https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap14%20-%20WebSocket.html

Comment: Yes, it works in every Browser exept Safari.

Comment: IOS & Safari have had support of Websockets since 2013, so what problem your having with Safari won't be websockets, unless your using a really old iPhone.. :)

Comment: Sorry that was a misunderstanding. Websocket works fine on iPhone. Thank you